# Copy contents of a file

Tags: copy-paste, file

I am trying to copy a whole bunch different files' contents into one big file. Is there a way to do this without having to open up each individual file and copying and pasting the contents? Is there a quick way to just right click a file and copy the contents directly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about plain text files or some other format?

Comment: Some are plain text, but just for completeness, I would like JUST the text, regardless of the format. So converting to plain text and then copying

Comment: There is no generic way for non-plain text files, you need to be specific about the application/format (Word doc, Pages etc.)

Comment: Ok. Then just plain text is ok.

Comment: You should be able to print them to one PDF using 'lpr', this way its also possible to keep the images and layout/style as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run the shell command **/usr/bin/textutil**  in the **Terminal.app** found in /Applications/Utilities/

**textutils**  Can be used to convert the text from one format to another.

But it also can  "Read the specified files, concatenate them, and write the result out as a single file in the indicated format."

**/usr/bin/textutil** *file/s* **-cat** *convert to format* **-output** *file output path*

It will concatenate differently formatted files.

The formats textutils can read and write to are

**txt, html, rtf, rtfd, doc, docx, wordml, odt, or webarchive**

Example

`/usr/bin/textutil foo1.txt foo2.txt foo1.rtf foo.html -cat txt -output /file/path/foo.txt`

Comment: Nice way to use to use textutil for doing this.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about plain text files, you can accomplish this in Terminal by running

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > bigfile.txt
```